# Use "cut" in shell script without space as delimiter

Tags: shell, delimiter, cut

I'm trying to write a script that reads the file content below and extract the value in the 6th column of each line, then print each line without the 6th column. The comma is used as the delimiter.

Input:

```
123,456,789,101,145,5671,hello world,goodbye for now
223,456,789,101,145,5672,hello world,goodbye for now
323,456,789,101,145,5673,hello world,goodbye for now
```

What I did was

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat test_input.txt`
do
    COLUMN=`echo $i | cut -f6 -d','`
    echo $i | cut -f1-5,7- -d',' >> test_$COLUMN.txt
done
```

The output I got was

test_5671.txt:

```
123,456,789,101,145,hello
```

test_5672.txt:

```
223,456,789,101,145,hello
```

test_5673.txt:

```
323,456,789,101,145,hello
```

The rest of "world, goodbye for now" was not written into the output files, because it seems like the space between "hello" and "world" was used as a delimiter?

How do I get the correct output

```
123,456,789,101,145,hello world,goodbye for now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with the *cut* command but with the *for* loop you're using. For the first loop run the variable *i* will only contain `123,456,789,101,145,5671,hello`.

If you insist to read the input file line-by-line (not very efficient), you'd better use a read-loop like this:

```
while read i
 do
  ...
 done < test_input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '123,456,789,101,145,5671,hello world,goodbye for now' | while IFS=, read -r one two three four five six seven eight rest
do
    echo "$six"
    echo "$one,$two,$three,$four,$five,$seven,$eight${rest:+,$rest}"
done
```

Prints:

```
5671
123,456,789,101,145,hello world,goodbye for now
```

See the `man bash` `Parameter Expansion` section for the `:+` syntax (essentially it outputs a comma and the `$rest` if `$rest` is defined *and* non-empty).

Also, [you shouldn't use `for` to loop over file contents](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 1):

As [ktf mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207512/use-cut-in-shell-script-without-space-as-delimiter/10207634#10207634), your problem is not with `cut` but with the way you're passing the lines into `cut`. The solution he/she has provided should work.

Alternatively, you could achieve the same behaviour with a line of `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if(i!=6) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF)?"\n":"," > "test_"$6".txt"}}' test_input.txt
```

For clarity, here's a verbose version:

```
awk -F, '  # "-F,": using comma as field separator
{ # for each line in file

  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {  # for each column

    sep = (i == NF) ? "\n" : ","  # column separator
    outfile = "test_"$6".txt"     # output file

    if (i != 6) {  # skip sixth column
      printf "%s%s", $i, sep > outfile
    }

  }

}' test_input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy method id to use **[tr](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29)** commende to convert the espace carracter into # and after doing the cat commande retranslate it into the espace.